# Insert new Element to SVGDocument from ALWAYS_DYNAMIC JSVGCanvas

Tags: java, dynamic, canvas, svg

What I want to do is to insert new Element to SVGDocument taken from JSVG canvas, so that it is should be automatically rendered and can be viewed.

So I have a JSVGCanvas, named SVGcanvas, and at LoadEventDispatcher I get the the SVGDocument, named doc, like this code:

```
this.SVGCanvas.addSVGLoadEventDispatcherListener(
    new SVGLoadEventDispatcherAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void svgLoadEventDispatchStarted (SVGLoadEventDispatcherEvent e) {
            doc = SVGCanvas.getSVGDocument();
            ...
        }
}
```

up is based on this: http://www.svgopen.org/2002/papers/kormann__developing_svg_apps_with_batik/

and then inside an event listener, I use this code

```
public void handleEvent (Event evt) {
    setRB(this.IDButtonGroup, this.ID);
    Element r = ((SVGDocument) doc).createElement("use");
    r.setAttribute("xhtml:href", "#cell");
    doc.getDocumentElement().appendChild(r);
}
```

based on this: http://wiki.apache.org/xmlgraphics-batik/DynamicSvgOffscreen

I thought it will work at onscreen, but I still can't get it to work. Anyone can help? The setRB function is work okay, so I don't think the problem is in the handler. I think the SVGCanvas not rendering the new doc. The doc should be SVGCanvas's, and because I had set the Document State of SVG Canvas to be ALWAYS_DYNAMIC, I thought it will be updated automatically. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the way I do it is right, but I do miss something.
based on this: http://www.carto.net/papers/svg/manipulating_svg_with_dom_ecmascript/
I should use

```
public void handleEvent (Event evt) {
    setRB(this.IDButtonGroup, this.ID);
    Element r = ((SVGDocument) doc).createElementNS(SVGNS,"use");
    r.setAttributeNS(XLINKNS, "href", "#cell");
    doc.getDocumentElement().appendChild(r);
}
```

and you are done! The cell defs is in the SVGCanvas now!
Oh yeah, the SVGNS and XLINKNS is NameSpace String Constant

```
String svgNS = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
var xlinkNS = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink";
```